# How Init a class in other class in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, class, model

I am doing a crud in angular, the issue is that I have an Entity model and another ContributingType. when I want to print the taxpayer type in the entity it doesn't let me. and I vote null. Any ideas

[[image]]

[image]

I want the field where it gives me null to give me an answer

Answer (score 0):

IF TipoContribuyente is an object This will work

```js
// Interface(dummy)
export class entities{
    id:string;
    name:string;
    taxPayer:taxPayer
}



export class taxPayer{
    id:string;
    name:string;
}
```

```html
// html

<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Tax Payer</th>
</tr>



<tr *ngfor let p of entities>
<td>{{p.id}}</td>
<td>{{p.name}}</td>
<td>{{p.taxPayer.name?true:false}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If TipoContribuyente is an array , you need to add index

```js
//Interface

export class entities{
    id:string;
    name:string;
    taxPayer:taxPayer[];
}
```

```html
// html

<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Tax Payer</th>
</tr>

<tr *ngfor let p of entities>
<td>{{p.id}}</td>
<td>{{p.name}}</td>
<td>{{p.taxPayer[0].name?true:false}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```